# how do I get solver the failed to create remote connection "remote" in local InfluxDB: 404 Not Found: path not found in influxdb 2?

Tags: influxdb-2, influxdb-python

I am try to create a remote connection from my OSS to my cloud in order to replica a bucket from local to the cloud.
however I'm stock in the "influx remote create"
below the command and flags 'm parsing:
*influx remote create --name remote --org-id "4e04a19955e6e25b" --token "_cdpoBmzhB3WhQM_0Mw7_2As49doaHpFuVFSZZbaM-xmaVck9jt_d0z_LIe3h6TPeIrtyYy-XG98eCkwqTx8jQ==" --remote-url "https://us-east-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com" --remote-api-token "eE8W3i9V90u5dHe-ICjHb5aTiDy92QrL260fW3ZLwFPhqXy0s8nqvEpEIHDA8R-lG3ZjU7Ya18M_HXZoxB3ACQ==" --remote-org-id "42c349f9005d5619"*
but I get this error, and not able figure out was wrong:
*Error: failed to create remote connection "remote" in local InfluxDB: 404 Not Found: path not found*

I have ubuntu 23.04,  ```
influxdb2-2.7.0,  influxdb2-client-2.7.1

```
Hope this enough to get the rgight answer 

I just want to know was is wrong and how to fix, 
I the documentation is no a clear guide on how to debbug this error.
```